# JSF AJAX type selectOneMenu

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate, jsf

I am new to JSF and was wondering if there is any way to do something like a "type ahead" that could be incorporated into a h:selectOneMenu scenario. I didn't know if this could be achieved using AJAX or something similar.

I saw this IBM article that looks very close to what I want to achieve -->

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rbdhelp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.egl.jsfsearch.tutorial.doc/topics/egl_lesson02-01-06.html

I am using Spring + Hibernate + JSF.

I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts on the easiest way to achieve this or any more resources (I am having a hard time finding material).

Comment: How do you want to incorporate an auto-completion-like mechanism into a combo box? Please explain the behavior you want to achieve in the interface.

Comment: Not a combo box(I don't think), I would like to achieve something very similar to the link posted above. Where the user can begin typing and a list is populated based on what they have started typing. Behaving in a sense the same way a Google search "predicts" what you are about to search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the PrimeFaces Autocomplete component:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf

This has all of the functionality that you are describing out of box and it is fairly easy to integrate into your application.  You would of course need to integrate PrimeFaces into your JSF application however there are plenty of online resources to help you with that.